# How to prove the following integral inequality with exponential function

Tags: real-analysis

It is known that $\alpha \geqslant1$,prove
$$\frac{1}{\alpha+\frac{1}{2}}<\int_{0}^{1}e^t(1-t)^{\alpha}dt<\frac{1}{\alpha}$$
I try to use $e^x>1+x$,but I can only prove it $\geqslant\frac{1}{\alpha+1}$.Then I thought about variable substitution, but I still couldn't get the right result,it is
$$\int_{0}^{1}e^t(1-t)^{\alpha}dt=\int_{0}^{1}e^{1-t}t^{\alpha}dt$$I want to know how to start to prove.Thanks!

Comment: I proved it $$\int_{0}^{1}e^t(1-t)^{\alpha}dt<\frac{1}{\alpha}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a partial answer.
$$\int_0^1 e^t(1-t)^\alpha> \int^1_0 (1+t)(1-t)^\alpha = \frac{1}{\alpha+1} +\frac{1}{\alpha^2+3\alpha+2}>\frac{1}{\alpha+\frac{1}{2}}$$
(the latter can be proved by simple algebriac manipulation)

Comment: Well,I didn't go on calculating.Thank you@razivo

Comment: Maybe$$\int^1_0 (1+t)(1-t)^\alpha= \frac{1}{\alpha+1} +\frac{1}{\alpha^2+3\alpha+2}$$

Comment: Maybe$$\frac{1}{\alpha+1} +\frac{1}{\alpha^2+3\alpha+2}\geqslant\frac{1}{\alpha+\frac{1}{2}}(\alpha\geqslant1)$$